# running a java application as superuser

Tags: java, macos, root

I have a build java application for mac I want to run the application as root/superuser all the time when the application opened up.  how would i go about to achieve this, I don't want to make a script that runs the jar or open terminal and type sudo to run the jar.  I want it where if they double click on the runnable jar it will prompt the user requesting for root right.

Comment: Why does your app need to run as root? There's very few reasons to actually do so (e.g. binding to a port < 1024), and far too many things that can go wrong if you don't do everything absolutely right.

Comment: because there some native code that needs to run as root that is tied to java.